# How to filter for branch in history view of mercurial eclipse plugin?

Tags: eclipse, mercurial

I sometimes want to see only a specific branch, not all in the eclipse mercurial history view. Is that possible?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like this is not working in eclipse. I use [TortoiseHg](http://tortoisehg.bitbucket.io/) now for that. There is a filter for exactly that:

[image]